# Is the spin quantum number conserved during a spin flip in the Kiatev honeycomb model?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment

It seems that a spin flip in Kitaev honeycomb model gives an itinerant Majorana fermion and a pair of $\pi$ fluxes. Because a spin flip causes $\Delta S = 1$ and $S = 1/2$ for Majorana fermion, does that mean the fluxes contain spin one-half? Thank you!

Comment: The Kitaev honeycomb model has no spin symmetry (no SO(3) or O(2)), so it does not really make much sense to ask what is the spin quantum number of excitations. If a hypothetical model with SO(3) spin symmetry has the same kind of behavior (spin flip = a Majorana + two pi fluxes), then the spin quantum numbers have to match from both sides: spin flip has S=1, Majorana should have S=1 as well, and fluxes have S=1/2.

Comment: @MengCheng So does no spin symmetry mean no spin conservation? Sorry I am a layman of QM so my question maybe a bit silly to you.